# Javascript: How to recursively group arrays based upon upcoming index value

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a situation where I want to group the arrays into chunks based upon the value of the upcoming index. Let's consider this example

#### Input

```
var tokens = [{
    tag: null,
    line: 'starting of the file'
},
{
    tag: 'each',
    line: null
}, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'foo bar'
}, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'baz'
}, {
    tag: 'endeach',
    line: null
}, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'hello world'
}]
```

#### Expected Output

```
[{
    tag: null,
    line: 'starting of the file'
},
{
    tag: 'each',
    line: null,
    childs: [{
        tag: null,
        line: 'foo bar'
    }, {
        tag: null,
        line: 'baz'
    }]
}, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'hello world'
}]
```

What really happening is all elements after the opening `each` tag are nested as childs. Now this can also happen recursively where there can be multiple `each` tags before the `endeach`.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce()`, whenever we encounter `each` we add the children array to the `container` array. Whenever we encounter `endeach` we remove the last array from `container`. We always items push to the last array in `container`. In the end the 1st array in `container` will include the tree:

```js
function fold(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(container, item) {
    if (item.tag === 'endeach') {
      container.pop();
      return container;
    }
    
    container[container.length - 1].push(item);

    if (item.tag === 'each') {
      item.children = [];

      container.push(item.children);
    }
    
    return container;
  }, [[]])[0];
}

var tokens = [{
    tag: null,
    line: 'starting of the file'
  }, {
    tag: 'each',
    line: null
  }, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'foo bar'
  }, {
    tag: 'each',
    line: null
  }, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'foo bar21'
  }, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'baz21'
  }, {
    tag: 'endeach',
    line: null
  }, {
    tag: 'each',
    line: null
  }, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'foo bar22'
  }, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'baz22'
  }, {
    tag: 'endeach',
    line: null
  },{
    tag: null,
    line: 'baz'
  }, {
    tag: 'endeach',
    line: null
  }, {
    tag: null,
    line: 'hello world'
  }
];

var result = fold(tokens);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works great, made it little more dynamic, since `each` is not the only tag.

Comment: Glad to hear. Refactored it a bit to use `reduce` instead of a for loop.